# react native pass value from drawer navigator

Tags: navigator, drawer

In App.js

```
const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home
    },

    Form: {
        screen: Form // how to pass value Id = 0
    },
    {
      ....
     }
})
```

in Form.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.navigation.getParam('Id', 1) !== 0) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use Screen Props:

```
const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home
    },

    Form: {
        screen: props => <Form {...props} id={0} />
    },
    {
      ....
     }
})
```

In `<Form {..props} id={0} />` you need to pass all props using {...props} so that navigation work correctly.

Then, you can access props from the Form screen and use it according to your use case.